# What does a ? mean between a variable and a method in C#

Tags: c#, variables, methods, operators

My code looks like this:

```
var newVariable = originalVariable?.method1().method2();
```

What does the "?" do between the originalVariable and the first method?

Answer (score -1):

The question mark between originalVariable and .method1() acts as a buffer to determine whether originalVariable is NULL.

If orginalVariable is null the methods after the "?" will not be executed.

Comment: If you're looking to add a question and answer first make sure there isn't already a question that is a duplicate.

Comment: Thanks @juharr for the reminder to look for the question that I have before asking it, something I did before creating this one. When searching for my question I didn't use the verbiage that was used in the question I copied and was unable to find it. Perhaps this question will link people using a different vocabulary to that page.